# Serial ports list in python gui

Tags: python, user-interface

I want a code in python to get a graphical user interface of list of com ports in a computer.Can somebody help me with this.This code should be operable in windows.I have tried this code which I am posting below:

```
import numpy  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #import matplotlib library
import pygame
import time
import random
from drawnow import *
for index in range(0,2):
    s1=list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())

def doNothing1() :
    print s1
def doNothing2() :
    print s3[0]
root=Tk()
menu=Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)
subMenu=Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="COMPORTS",menu=subMenu)

s1=str(s1)
s1=s1.split("(")
#s2=s1.split()
s2=s1[0]
s4=s1[1]
s3=s2.split("'")
s5=s4.split("'")




subMenu.add_command(label=s3[1],command=doNothing1)
subMenu.add_command(label=s5[1],command=doNothing2)






root.mainloop()
```